# Make the declared variable inside a trigger append its value if more than one condition is met

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Well I was writing a trigger and I wanted that the declared variable v_message to append every time the condition is met. So for example if the first two statements are met the v_message should be something like "Invalid account Invalid amount". I must also find a way to separate these two messages by a space if the v_message already contains some sort of an error message as it wont be readable if you had something like this "Invalid accountInvalid amount".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkPayments
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_payments
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    v_message VARCHAR(100 CHAR);
        v_is_valid CHAR(1) := 'N';
BEGIN 

    IF getActiveUser(getOrderUsername(:new.order_id)) = 0 
    THEN v_message := 'Invalid account';

    ELSIF isValidAmount(:new.payment_amount) = 0
    THEN v_message := 'Invalid amount';

    ELSIF checkOrderExist(:new.order_id) = 0 
    THEN v_message := 'Invalid order ID';

    ELSIF (getValidOrderPayments(:new.order_id) + :new.payment_amount ) > getOrderTotal(:new.order_id)
    THEN  v_message := 'Payment exceeds total';

    ELSE v_message := 'OK' ; 
        v_is_valid := 'Y';

    END IF;

    :new.payment_id:= seq_payment_id.nextval;
    :new.payment_date:= LOCALTIMESTAMP;
    :new.payment_message := v_message;
    :new.is_valid := v_is_valid;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkPayments
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_payments
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    v_message VARCHAR(100 CHAR);
        v_is_valid CHAR(1) := 'N';
BEGIN 

    v_is_valid := 'Y';

    IF getActiveUser(getOrderUsername(:new.order_id)) = 0 
        THEN v_message := 'Invalid account';
        v_is_valid := 'N';
    END IF;

    IF isValidAmount(:new.payment_amount) = 0
        THEN v_message := v_message || ' Invalid amount';
        v_is_valid := 'N';
    END IF;

    IF checkOrderExist(:new.order_id) = 0 
        THEN v_message := v_message || ' Invalid order ID';
        v_is_valid := 'N';
    END IF;

    IF (getValidOrderPayments(:new.order_id) + :new.payment_amount ) > getOrderTotal(:new.order_id)
        THEN  v_message := v_message || ' Payment exceeds total';
        v_is_valid := 'N';
    END IF;

    IF v_is_valid = 'Y'
        THEN v_message := 'OK' ;    
    END IF;

    :new.payment_id:= seq_payment_id.nextval;
    :new.payment_date:= LOCALTIMESTAMP;
    :new.payment_message := trim(v_message);
    :new.is_valid := v_is_valid;

END;
/
```

Comment: Would the trim(v_message) trim out all the leading and trailing spaces as I am trying to end up with something like this "Invalid account Invalid amount" instead of like this "Invalid accountInvalid amount"  ?

Comment: I tried the code but it didn't concatenate the any two error messages although I have an instance where the payment has an invalid amount and an invalid account, it just added the first message only "Invalid account".

Comment: oh - i didnt think to carefully.. these should all be different IF statements not ELSE

Comment: Yes I noticed the mistake before you edited the code and put an if statement to check if the message is null , if so set to 'Ok' and 'Y'. It's almost the same solution like you posted. Thanks a lot for your help : )